# How to prevent users from seeing other's messages in websocket connection?

Tags: jquery, laravel, websocket

I just noticed in my chat application that a logged in user could actually see other's messages through the chrome > network > websocket messages.

[image]

What are some ways to hide sensitive data such as the sender Id, message, etc?

Currently I have only one websocket channel for the entire chat application, is this the correct way to do it? or it is better to initiate one channel per chat between user A and user B?

Comment: If users receive events that they shouldn't receive through websockets, it's called a leak. You never ever want that kind of data leaking everywhere to all of your users. First, because it will send a lot of useless data everywhere (since you seem to broadcast your messages) and because private data must remain private. You seem to dispatch message with a boradcasting feature. I know nothing about laravel websockets, but I'm sure that you should considere to read their doc about channels. IMHO, channels are made for that purpose.

Comment: @Ariart Thanks for your input and I totally agree with you. I think I should create one one channel per chat conversation, that makes more sense right?